# Plot labelled and unlabeled data matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have three list which are X, Y, Z

```
X = [[0.67910803031180977, 0.1443997264255876], [0.57, 0.87], [0.545, 0.854], [0.645, 0.1254], [0.645, 0.1354], [0.62, 0.83], [0.6945, 0.144], [0.9945, 0.45244], [0.235, 0.7754], [0.7, 0.85]]

Y = [0, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1]

Z = [0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1]
```

Where,

```
X is the dataset,
Y is labelset where 0 means "Normal", 1 means "LL" and -1 means "Unlabelled"
Z is outputset in which labels from Y is propagated to unlabelled labels.
```

Now, i am trying to plot a figure where one subplot contains the dataset as cluster with respect to each label from Y it belongs to and another subplot showing dataset with respect to Z.

I tried [code from this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/semi_supervised/plot_label_propagation_structure.html#example-semi-supervised-plot-label-propagation-structure-py) but i am not able to do it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing at what you want, but here's an example of plotting the X values with colors determined by the Y and Z lists respectively. It's using a lot of default behavior -- color values between 0 and 1 get plotted into a default colorbar, iirc -- but you could make a more complicated function and pass a list of (rgb) or (rgba) values instead.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import array
X = array([[0.67910803031180977, 0.1443997264255876], [0.57, 0.87],
           [0.545, 0.854], [0.645, 0.1254], [0.645, 0.1354], [0.62, 0.83],
           [0.6945, 0.144], [0.9945, 0.45244], [0.235, 0.7754], [0.7, 0.85]])
Y = [0, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1]
Z = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

# for readability mostly
Xx = X.T[0]
Xy = X.T[1]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.scatter(Xx, Xy, c=map(lambda c: 0.3 * c + 0.5, Y), s=50, alpha=0.75)
ax1.set_xlabel('Y labels')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.scatter(Xx, Xy, c=map(lambda c: 0.3 * c + 0.5, Z), s=50, alpha=0.75)
ax2.set_xlabel('Z labels')
plt.show()
```

[image]